# Magento 2- Added widget in static block is not visible in front end

Tags: magento2, theme, widget, new-products

I have created a static block and within the block, I have added an embedded code for **new_products** widget.
All content is visible in the front end except the widget.

**Embedded Code:**

> {{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget"
>   display_type="new_products" products_count="10"
>   template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

**Current Theme:-**

*https://themeforest.net/item/starbella-responsive-magento-2-theme/23641097*

Please suggest.

Comment: have you manually changed new_grid.phtml file?

Comment: no, I think there is some indexing problem, as while indexing its showing invalidate indexer

Comment: Do you mean Magento indexing?

Comment: You can contact  theme forest support. They will help you

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue has been fixed, there was a Magento indexing problem.